# How do I set default / active tools for a bokeh gridplot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, bokeh

If one wants to define the active (default) tools for a bokeh plot, it can be set by passing "active_drag", "active_inspect", ... parameters to the figure instance as documented [**here**](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting.html#bokeh.plotting.figure.Figure).

I have not yet succeeded to set the standard-active tools for a gridplot, in which all single plots share a toolbar. This the relevant part of my code:

```
    tools = [
            PanTool(),
            BoxZoomTool(),
            WheelZoomTool(),
            UndoTool(),
            RedoTool(),
            ResetTool(),
            SaveTool(),
            HoverTool(tooltips=[
                ("Value", "$y")
                ])
            ]

    x_axes_range = Range1d(self.data.index[0], self.data.index[-1])

    for plot_type, plot_settings in pcfg.plot_types[self.name].items():

        plots.append(figure(x_axis_type="datetime", title=plot_type, plot_height = 400, x_range = x_axes_range, 
                            tools = tools, active_drag = None, active_inspect = None, active_scroll = None, active_tap = None))
    ...

    plots[plot_counter].line(self.data.index, self.data[parameter], color=parameter_settings[1], legend=parameter_settings[0])

...

gp = gridplot(plots, ncols = 1, sizing_mode = "scale_width")

script, div = components(gp)
```

So what happens is that the "BoxZoomTool()" is selected as active tool on the website I display it on, although I set the active tools to None in the figure initializations, but the available tools are those I passed to the `figure()` inits.

I did see the "toolbar_option" [here](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/layouts.html#bokeh.layouts.gridplot), but I do not see how I can change the active tools using that parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Update 6/4/2020

Well, it seems that somebody created a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/10107) and the [changes were already merged](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/10095). Let's see if this is working in the next Bokeh Version

---

## Old Answer

### Research

I believe you only can change the logo with `toolbar_options` like this:

```
toolbar_options=dict(logo='gray')
```

I hope there will more options in the future.

I have checked how to achieve what you want (I needed to do it as well) and it seems that the gridplot uses an special toolbar to join all the plot toolbars together: a [**ProxyToolbar**](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/tools.html#bokeh.models.tools.ProxyToolbar)

```
# Make the grid
tools = []
rows = []

for row in children:
    row_tools = []
    row_children = []
    for item in row:
        if merge_tools:
            if item is not None:
                for plot in item.select(dict(type=Plot)):
                    row_tools = row_tools + plot.toolbar.tools
                    plot.toolbar_location = None
        if item is None:
            width, height = 0, 0
            for neighbor in row:
                if isinstance(neighbor, Plot):
                    width = neighbor.plot_width
                    height = neighbor.plot_height
                    break
            item = Spacer(width=width, height=height)
        if isinstance(item, LayoutDOM):
            item.sizing_mode = sizing_mode
            if isinstance(item, Plot):
                if plot_width:
                    item.plot_width = plot_width
                if plot_height:
                    item.plot_height = plot_height
            row_children.append(item)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Only LayoutDOM items can be inserted into Grid")
    tools = tools + row_tools
    rows.append(Row(children=row_children, sizing_mode=sizing_mode))

grid = Column(children=rows, sizing_mode=sizing_mode)

if not merge_tools:
    return grid

if toolbar_location:
    proxy = ProxyToolbar(tools=tools, **toolbar_options)
    toolbar = ToolbarBox(toolbar=proxy, toolbar_location=toolbar_location)
```

The tools are gathered in a list to assign them to the special toolbar. I don´t see that the default active elements are collected anywhere.

### Alternative solution

So what you could do is to create a toolbar and the gridplot manually, where you can set the attributes you want to the Toolbar class. Check this example I have built:

```
from bokeh.models import Button, ColumnDataSource, Range1d, Toolbar, ToolbarBox
from bokeh.models.tools import HoverTool, WheelZoomTool, PanTool, CrosshairTool
from bokeh.layouts import layout
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc, figure

x_range = Range1d(start=0, end=10)
y_range = Range1d(start=0, end=10)

# ------------------- PLOT 1 --------------------------- #

plot_1 = figure(
    title='First figure',
    width=400,
    height=400,
    x_range=x_range,
    y_range=y_range,
    toolbar_location=None,
    x_axis_label='x axis',
    y_axis_label='y axis',
)

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [4, 3, 2, 1]

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))

plot_1.circle(
    x='x',
    y='y',
    source=source,
    radius=0.5,
    fill_alpha=0.6,
    fill_color='green',
    line_color='black',
)

# ------------------- PLOT 2 --------------------------- #

plot_2 = figure(
    name='plot_2',
    title='Second figure',
    width=400,
    height=400,
    x_range=x_range,
    y_range=y_range,
    toolbar_location=None,
    x_axis_label='x axis',
    y_axis_label='y axis',
)

plot_2.circle(
    x='x',
    y='y',
    source=source,
    radius=0.5,
    fill_alpha=0.6,
    fill_color='red',
    line_color='black',
)

# ---------------- ADD TOOLS TO THE PLOT --------------------- #

wheel_zoom = WheelZoomTool()
pan_tool = PanTool()
hover = HoverTool()
crosshair = CrosshairTool()
tools = (wheel_zoom, pan_tool, hover, crosshair)

toolbar = Toolbar(
    tools=[wheel_zoom, pan_tool, hover, crosshair],
    active_inspect=[crosshair],
    # active_drag =                         # here you can assign the defaults
    # active_scroll =                       # wheel_zoom sometimes is not working if it is set here
    # active_tap 
)

toolbar_box = ToolbarBox(
    toolbar=toolbar,
    toolbar_location='left'
)

plot_1.add_tools(*tools)
plot_2.add_tools(*tools)

# ----------------- PLOT LAYOUT -------------------------- #

layout_1 = layout(
    children=[
        [toolbar_box, plot_1, plot_2],
    ],
    sizing_mode='fixed',
)

curdoc().add_root(layout_1)
```

**Note**: I am doing some tests and sometimes it is not working well. The tools are marked as default but randomly don´t work, I am afraid it has something to do with the JavaScript and asyncronous tasks. So maybe we should wait.

### Second Alternative Solution

I think I found a solution that always work. This is a kind of workaround. In my example I use two plots, but only the toolbar of the first plot is shown. Anyway you need to set the default toolbar values to both plots.

```py
from bokeh.models import Button, ColumnDataSource, Range1d, Toolbar, ToolbarBox
from bokeh.models.tools import HoverTool, WheelZoomTool, PanTool, CrosshairTool, LassoSelectTool
from bokeh.layouts import layout
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc, figure

x_range = Range1d(start=0, end=10)
y_range = Range1d(start=0, end=10)

# ------------------- PLOT 1 --------------------------- #

plot_1 = figure(
    title='First figure',
    width=400,
    height=400,
    x_range=x_range,
    y_range=y_range,
    toolbar_location='left',        # show only the toolbar of the first plot
    tools='',
    x_axis_label='x axis',
    y_axis_label='y axis',
)

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [4, 3, 2, 1]

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))

plot_1.circle(
    x='x',
    y='y',
    source=source,
    radius=0.5,
    fill_alpha=0.6,
    fill_color='green',
    line_color='black',
)

# ------------------- PLOT 2 --------------------------- #

plot_2 = figure(
    name='plot_2',
    title='Second figure',
    width=400,
    height=400,
    x_range=x_range,
    y_range=y_range,
    toolbar_location=None,
    tools='',
    x_axis_label='x axis',
    y_axis_label='y axis',
)

plot_2.circle(
    x='x',
    y='y',
    source=source,
    radius=0.5,
    fill_alpha=0.6,
    fill_color='red',
    line_color='black',
)

# ---------------- ADD TOOLS TO THE PLOT --------------------- #

wheel_zoom = WheelZoomTool()
lasso_select = LassoSelectTool()
pan_tool = PanTool()
hover = HoverTool()
crosshair = CrosshairTool()
tools = (wheel_zoom, lasso_select, pan_tool, hover, crosshair)

plot_1.add_tools(*tools)
plot_2.add_tools(*tools)

plot_1.toolbar.active_inspect=[crosshair]     # defaults added to the first plot
plot_1.toolbar.active_scroll=wheel_zoom
plot_1.toolbar.active_tap=None
plot_1.toolbar.active_drag=lasso_select

plot_2.toolbar.active_inspect=[crosshair]     # defaults added to the second plot
plot_2.toolbar.active_scroll=wheel_zoom
plot_2.toolbar.active_tap=None
plot_2.toolbar.active_drag=lasso_select

# ----------------- PLOT LAYOUT -------------------------- #

layout_1 = layout(
    children=[
        [plot_1, plot_2],
    ],
    sizing_mode='fixed',
)

curdoc().add_root(layout_1)
```

### Developers Feedback

In fact, Bryan (bokeh developer) told me on the chat

> I was going to actually answer that default tool activation and grid plots had never been considered together and was not supported yet, tho if you have found something that works for your specific use case that's probably the best possible. As you say it's not generally the case that users should have to work with toolbars directly, they are finicky for a number of reasons.

Comment: Thank you very much for your extensive answer. I have not yet decided whether this makes me use another library. If not, I will probably give it a try using your code. Also thanks for the developer input!

Comment: @Corrumpo You are welcome. I think I found a better way to do it, without asyncronous problems. Take a look at  my **Second Alternative Solution** I have written on my answer

Comment: Has this been raised as an issue on the Bokeh issue tracker?

Comment: No @chris, as Bryan said that is not supported yet. Actually I would write two issues (feature requests), one to enable "default tool activation" on Gridplots, and another one to "work with toolbars directly"