# Deactivate specific Hover tool in Bokeh html figures?

Tags: python, hover, bokeh, toolbar

I want that the pan-tool of Hover toolbar is set OFF when I open the html-page.
By default the tool is ON. How to set it off by default?
[Figure - Trying to "deactivate" pan tool by default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qzjG.png)

The problem appears to arise when using shared x-axis (grid plot).
The command `p.toolbar.active_drag = None` does not help; pan tool remains active.
Any Ideas how to fix this?

**Example**

```
from bokeh.plotting import ColumnDataSource, figure, output_file, show,output_notebook,reset_output
from bokeh.models import HoverTool,Grid
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
import datetime

reset_output()
output_notebook()
tools = 'pan,wheel_zoom,xbox_select,reset'
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(time=[2231231233123, 1431231233123, 1731231233123],y=[2, 5, 3],))                         
source2 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(time=[1231231233123, 1431231233123, 1731231233123],x=[1, 2, 3],))

# Figure 1:
p = figure(width=400, height=200, x_axis_type="datetime",tools=tools)
p.circle('time', 'y', size=20, source=source)
p.toolbar.active_drag = None

# Figure 2:
p2 = figure(x_range=p.x_range,width=400,height=200,x_axis_type="datetime",tools=tools)
p2.circle('time', 'x', size=20, source=source2)
p2.toolbar.active_drag = None

grid = gridplot([p, p2], ncols=1)
show (grid)
```

**Illustrating Example**
[image: Figure illustrating the problem]

Comment: I opend an issue on GitHub [#11839](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/11839). Let's see what will come.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
p.toolbar.active_drag = None
```

You can read more one the official [documentation](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#setting-the-active-tools) it the section about "setting the active tools".

**Minimal Example**

```
from bokeh.plotting import show, figure, output_notebook
output_notebook()

p = figure(width=300, height=300, tools='pan')
p.line([1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5])
p.toolbar.active_drag = None
show(p)
```

[image: Deactivated TapTool]

Comment: Thanks @mosc9575. 

The problem appears to arise when using "grid plot". I updated the question with an example.

Comment: @kko This is very interesting and I don't know any solution. I tried `grid.children[0].toolbar.toolbars[0].active_drag = None` and I thought this should make the change, but it does not. I am sorry.

Comment: Thanks @mosc9575.  Maybe there is no solution when using grids: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49282688/how-do-i-set-default-active-tools-for-a-bokeh-gridplot